# Sort Dictionary inside Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

**I have a csv file in which I need fetch top 5 cities along with total casualties in that city and I have done most of the code but stuck how to Sort Dictionaries in desc-order which is inside numpy array.

**

```
city_dict = {}
with open('terrorismData.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_obj:
    Data = csv.DictReader(file_obj, skipinitialspace = True)
    
        
    for row in Data:
        if row['Country'] == 'India':
            if row['Killed'] == '':
                row['Killed'] = 0
            if row['Wounded'] == '':
                row['Wounded'] = 0
            
            total_casuality = int(float(row['Killed'])) + int(float(row['Wounded']))
            if row['City'] != 'Unknown':            
                if row['City'] in city_dict:
                    city_dict[row['City']] += total_casuality
                else:
                    city_dict[row['City']] = total_casuality
                
    np_city = np.array(city_dict)
    print(np_city)
```

> **The output (I get) on which I need to apply Sorting **
> {'New Delhi': 2095, 'Samastipur': 4, 'Bombay': 210, 'Imphal': 603, 'Aizawl': 2, 'Amapur': 2, 'Raisikah': 1, 'Champhai': 1, 'Jamshedpur': 32, 'Chennai': 366, 'Chiaplant': 1, 'Tindol': 7, 'Calcutta': 57, 'Tirupattur': 6, 'Gauhati': 112, 'Jorhat': 3, 'Massad': 1, 'Chandigarh': 333, 'Jodhpur': 2, 'Amritsar': 768, 'Tipaimukh': 6, 'Guwahati': 822, 'Harchowal': 1, 'Mothan Wala': 2, 'Qadian': 7, 'Baloda Bazar': 10 }

> The Output (I want).
> {'New Delhi': 2095, 'Amritsar': 768, 'Imphal': 603, 'Chandigarh': 333, Bombay': 210, .......'Harchowal': 1}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Why did you make an array from the `dict`?  It doesn't help with this task.

Comment: It's question requirement that, I have to convert Dictionary into numpy array first and then sort it.

Comment: You haven't converted anything.  You just embedded the dict object in an object dtype array.  To do the sort you still have have to take it back out!  Which make me wonder about the purpose of the question.  What's the 'array' step supposed to be teaching you?  Or did you mis-read the question?  You could have read the `csv` as numpy array (with dtype to make a structured array), or as pandas dataframe.  And then sorted the resulting (structured) array or dataframe.  You wouldn't be using a `dict` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary is:

```
city_dict = {'New Delhi': 2095, 'Samastipur': 4, 'Bombay': 210, 'Imphal': 603, 'Aizawl': 2, 'Amapur': 2, 'Raisikah': 1, 'Champhai': 1, 'Jamshedpur': 32, 'Chennai': 366, 'Chiaplant': 1, 'Tindol': 7, 'Calcutta': 57, 'Tirupattur': 6, 'Gauhati': 112, 'Jorhat': 3, 'Massad': 1, 'Chandigarh': 333, 'Jodhpur': 2, 'Amritsar': 768, 'Tipaimukh': 6, 'Guwahati': 822, 'Harchowal': 1, 'Mothan Wala': 2, 'Qadian': 7, 'Baloda Bazar': 10 }

np_city = np.array(city_dict)

print(np_city)
```

#output

```
array({'New Delhi': 2095, 'Samastipur': 4, 'Bombay': 210, 'Imphal': 603, 'Aizawl': 2, 'Amapur': 2, 'Raisikah': 1, 'Champhai': 1, 'Jamshedpur': 32, 'Chennai': 366, 'Chiaplant': 1, 'Tindol': 7, 'Calcutta': 57, 'Tirupattur': 6, 'Gauhati': 112, 'Jorhat': 3, 'Massad': 1, 'Chandigarh': 333, 'Jodhpur': 2, 'Amritsar': 768, 'Tipaimukh': 6, 'Guwahati': 822, 'Harchowal': 1, 'Mothan Wala': 2, 'Qadian': 7, 'Baloda Bazar': 10},
      dtype=object)
```

Now, you have to access this dictionary from `np.array`

You have to do:

```
np_city.item()
```

To sort and reverse them, use `np_city.item().items()`:

```
{key: value for key, value in sorted(np_city.item().items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)}
```

#output

```
{'New Delhi': 2095, 'Guwahati': 822, 'Amritsar': 768, 'Imphal': 603, 'Chennai': 366, 'Chandigarh': 333, 'Bombay': 210, 'Gauhati': 112, 'Calcutta': 57, 'Jamshedpur': 32, 'Baloda Bazar': 10, 'Tindol': 7, 'Qadian': 7, 'Tirupattur': 6, 'Tipaimukh': 6, 'Samastipur': 4, 'Jorhat': 3, 'Aizawl': 2, 'Amapur': 2, 'Jodhpur': 2, 'Mothan Wala': 2, 'Raisikah': 1, 'Champhai': 1, 'Chiaplant': 1, 'Massad': 1, 'Harchowal': 1}
```

Comment: `np_city.item()` just takes that dict back out of the array, back where you started. :)

Comment: @hpaulj yes you are right:)